# Sufficient conditions for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In analysis, given a function with domain a product space,  there exists a sufficient condition for it to be differentiable, namely that the partial derivatives exist **and** are continuous.

> I was wondering if there exists in topology a sufficient condition for a map from a product space $F:A\times B \to C$ to be continuous.

Comment: If $F$ is a composition of continuous mapping, assuming $A,B$ and $C$ are topological spaces.

Comment: If I understand the analogy correctly you are looking for some weaker condition then continuity analogously to continuity being weker then differntiability? One such condition would be "$f$ maps connected subsets to connected subsets" (a.k.a. $f$ has intermediate value property). However I don't know any additional condition that would imply continuity.

Comment: My point is the following: If I rely only on the definition of differentiability , then functions such as $e^{xy}$ would have to be checked by definition if they are differentiable. Having a sufficient condition, means I can calculate the partials and see if they are continuous easily. So I can conclude that $e^{xy}$ is differentiable. I want some similar sufficient condition that will allow me to check if $F$ is continous, without going to the definition of continuity every single time.

Comment: @EEEB There is no analogous condition on $A\times B\to C$ that I am aware of. People usually go through the definition and/or the composition rule. There is such condition on $f:A\to B\times C$ though: $f$ is continuous if and only if $\pi\circ f$ is continous for every projection $\pi$.

Comment: @freakish It seems that within topology (according to Munkres) indeed as you said there is no useful criterion. We could, using analysis, check that it is differentiable, by existence and continuity of partial derivatives, and then use differentiability implies continuity. Does that sound right?